# Test set error estimation under a small sample size

Tags: machine-learning, small-sample, model-evaluation

What are some of the plausible approaches to estimate the test set error when you have a very small sample set available (specifically, when the small sample size does not justify using a hold-out set)?

When using a linear regression model or a model that adopts a Maximum-Likelihood-based approach to estimate the parameters, I can think of using Adjusted R^2, AIC, or BIC as estimators of the test set error.

Are there any other sound approaches to adopt?

Comment: The methods you mentioned are model selection criteria. They can be used to select a model out of multiple alternatives, or to tune hyperparameters, but they don't directly estimate generalization performance. Is model selection actually what you're asking about?

Comment: I'm asking about the generalization error. The reason we can use the above-mentioned methods to select between models is that they provide an estimate of the generalization error.

Answer (score 0):

I would not call any of those metrics (adjusted $R^2$, AIC, BIC) estimations of the testing error, but they are intended to perform a similar function, and all of them can be informative. Nothing will be as unbiased as using an actual testing set, of course.

To get something that takes a form that is more similar to testing error, I would suggest using cross validation and looking at the average of the cross validation error across each folds. One option in R is the caret package, which lets you do cross validation multiple times and average across of them (e.g. 5-fold CV 3 times, so it's training/testing 15 regressions).

Comment: Thanks. The problem is that, I think, with a small sample size the estimation obtained from cross validation would be highly variable.

Comment: It likely will be, but doing repeated CV instead of a single pass of CV should help you arrive at a mean error that is more reliable. Also, your full training set is only 10-25% larger than each CV fold, assuming you do 5-10 fold CV. So if you look at your CV models and notice their coefficients (assuming you're doing linear regression) vary wildly, that's a good sign that you simply don't have enough data to be confident about the generalizability of your model.